# How to organise routing using CouchDB as a main database?

Tags: routes, couchdb, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Can you please advice me, how to organise routing using CouchDB as a main database?

I have about 10 databases, with different content types, such as `company`, `job`, `topic` and `blog`.

Schema between databases more or less the same. All documents include following fields:

```
{
  url: "actual-path",
  redirects: [
    "old-path",
    "another-old-path"
  ]
}
```

Every request from a client, I'm querying each database by requested url. Once I get a document, I'm doing 200 or 301, otherwise 404.

The problem with this method is, I need to do at least 10 requests to database every page load. And with services there I need to pay for a threshold - it's expansive.

Is there a better way to organise it? I have two ways in my mind:

1. Make a middle server which will index all redirects somewhere into Redis.
2. Replicate just redirects into separated table, within CouchDB, and query only that table. Not sure that it's possible.

Comment: Why don't you put everything into the same database and separate them using a certain key (eg: type, collection,table)? This will reduce the queries to 1

Comment: Because we have different permissions for different databases.

Comment: Either of your solutions would work.  I like the suggestion of keeping a quick lookup version of these redirects in Redis especially since you're using this information on every request.  You could also have a process subscribed to the changes API to keep the information in Redis updated.